# Replacing old floor boards before sanding. Will the color match?

Tags: flooring

I have some areas in my 70s home that has:

1. Some small nail holes from old carpet
2. A couple of darker water stains as well.
3. Some squeaky areas due to nailed subfloor

If I were to remove some flooring to fix these issues & replace it after with newer boards, will sanding the entire floor of the house then "neutralize" everything so colors match before we finish it?

Comment: If you sand far enough you're left with raw wood, and it becomes a matter of the wood's natural color. That's really all there is to it.